# Remapping vim end of line key

Tags: vim, text-editor

One of the big annoyances when using vim in mac keyboard is the absence of Home and End keys. Although there is a work around in vim namely

```
$ for  End of line 
0 for Beginning of line (both in <Esc> mode)
```

I find it unintuitive as $ is on the left side of the keyboard and takes you to the rightmost line of text whereas 0 being on the right side takes you to the beginning of the line. 
Is there a way to remap the keys with 9 for beginning of line and 0 for end of line?

I tried the following in my ~/.vimrc

```
inoremap <Esc>9 <Esc>0
inoremap <Esc>0 <Esc>$
```

but it doesn't seem to take effect and the old key combinations are still in place. Help me out! Also let me know the drawbacks of doing this (if any)? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that `inoremap` is for insert mode mappings? Does `nnoremap 0 $` work for you?

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Btw how to get to the beginning of line and end of line without losing insert mode?

Comment: You can type `<Home>` and `<End>` on a Mac keyboard via `<Fn + Left>` and `<Fn + Right>`.  `<Fn + Up>` and `<Fn + Down>` do `<PgUp>` and `<PgDn>`.

Comment: Just as a trivia tidbit, the reason `$` and `^` (which is arguably more useful than `0`) are end and beginning of line, respectively, is because those are the regexp tokens for end of line and beginning of line -- `^hello` matches hello's that start a line, `hello$` matches hello's that end a line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`inoremap` is meant for insert mode mappings. What you're looking for is `nnoremap`. For example, you could try this:

```
nnoremap 0 $
nnoremap 9 0
inoremap <C-A> <Home>
inoremap <C-E> <End>
```

However, personally I would not remap the 9 as you might randomly need it someday (for say `9gg` or `9j`). Instead I'd go for `Q`, `K`, `U` or `S` as they are hardly used.

In fact, I would probably recommend just leaving it the way it is. `$` is actually quite intuitive when you learn about regular expressions. It is a bit hard to hit, but in general you won't need it that much because you have many commands such as `D` that map to `d$`. And it will also be easier when you ever have to work with a vanilla vim.